# Google's new reCaptcha breaks angular with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, recaptcha

When I tick the recaptcha box, ui-router seems to break down. All links with ui-sref attributes on the page stops working, but I get no error messages. Please look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QTMIC7Tuf0h71jbodofT?p=preview) that I've set up. Do you have any idea of what might be the cause?

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: function() {
      grecaptcha.render('captcha', {
        sitekey: "--sitekey--"
      })
    }
  })
  .state('other', {
    templateUrl: 'other.html'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
})
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-rc.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ui-router@*" data-semver="0.2.13" src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.13/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
```

home.html

```
<h1>Home</h1>

<p>Click the re-captcha, then try to change state by clicking the link below.</p>

<p><a ui-sref="other">Go to other state</a></p>

<div id="captcha"></div>
```

other.html is irrelevant.

**UPDATE**
I've noticed that the state transition fails only when the target state has a url defined, and I've managed to narrow it down to the following piece of code in the ui-router source (ui-sref directive):

```
element.bind("click", function(e) {
    var button = e.which || e.button;
    if ( !(button > 1 || e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey || e.shiftKey || element.attr('target')) ) {
      // HACK: This is to allow ng-clicks to be processed before the transition is initiated:
      var transition = $timeout(function() {
        $state.go(ref.state, params, options);
      });
      e.preventDefault();

      // if the state has no URL, ignore one preventDefault from the <a> directive.
      var ignorePreventDefaultCount = isAnchor && !newHref ? 1: 0;
      e.preventDefault = function() {
        if (ignorePreventDefaultCount-- <= 0)
          $timeout.cancel(transition);
      };
    }
  });
```

As you can see, the e.preventDefault function is being overridden to cancel the timeout that will fire the state change. If you comment out this piece of code in the above binder the state transition works:

```
//e.preventDefault = function() {
//    if (ignorePreventDefaultCount-- <= 0)
//        $timeout.cancel(transition);
//};
```

Normally ui-router calls e.preventDefault() once per click on each anchor link, but when the reCaptcha is ticked it seems to be called twice. I am guessing that this might be connected to the problem, but I'm not 100% sure. Maybe someone with better debugging skills can understand what is happening. [Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JKXnt6vV5uaNYfYyoRRB?p=preview) that demonstrated this behaviour.

Comment: Works if you use ngRoute: http://plnkr.co/edit/fF1ClQPA2IALch9Bgoib?p=preview

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha ?

Comment: I've tried all angular modules that I could find, including the one from vividCortex, but I get the same behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

I've found a simple way to solve the problem with any kind of router on angular. when grecaptha got undefined, it's means that we've in your case a synchronization problem. So in my/ your controller you should load the script by using for example << $.getScript("URL") >>

SO : 
In HTML 
`<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="YourSiteKey"></div>`

And in your Controller :
`$.getScript("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js");`

Here your let grecaptcha do this work like if you were loading your page for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when using angular routing.

You can solve this problem by placing this code :

in index.html

> `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"></script>`

in your script.js :

> ```
> var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
> app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
> $stateProvider.state('home', 
>         {
>             url: '/',
>             templateUrl: 'home.html',
>             controller: function() {
>                  function onloadCallback() {
>                      grecaptcha.render('yourHTMLElementId', {
>                           'sitekey' : 'yourSiteKey'
>                      });
>                  }
>                  onloadCallback();
>            }
>         })
>     .state('other', {
>         templateUrl: 'other.html'
>     });
>     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
> })
> ```